# How can I retain the destination parameter when a user registers a new account with email verification?

Tags: 9

This is for a Drupal 9 website.

How can we retain the destination after a user registers a new account that requires email verification?

Example workflow:

User clicks to create a new node but does not have permissions.

They are present with the registration page where the destination parameter is set from the previous content/add URL.

They fill in and submit the form and are instructed to check their email.

User click the one-time login link from the email and set their password.

- The destination parameter is not retained in the one-time login link so once the user clicks it and sets their password their original destination is lost.